# kubectl commands takes lot of time execute and freezing entire system

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

when ever I run a kubectl command, it takes a lot of time to execute, mostly > 1 minute and some time between 40seconds to 1 minute. However, during this execution time, the entire system freeze if I use keyboard to switch between applications (clicking with trackpad has no impact luckily) and I cannot perform any other action, like a mouse click or switch between applications unless the command executes.

Is there a way to speed up? I've done a time analysis using the time command on zsh + mac.

Using gcloud 386.0, and installed kubectl components using gcloud, below is the outcome.

```
$ time kubectl get pods -n my-name-space

NAME                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
abc-svc-84699b749c-sgc5n                          2/2     Running            0          4h2m
def-7b6c594798-mtsqd                              2/2     Running            17         13d
pqr-call-69bb7c5d4b-64twc                         2/2     Running            0          3h45m

kubectl get pods -n my-name-space  0.54s user 0.52s system 0% cpu 1:59.29 total
```

Observing the total time, it took almost 2 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down if it's a server side latency or client side ? If it's a server side, changing to different machine or using different client like curl would not help. However,  if it's client side issue , you may notice performance difference when different client/or machine is used.

Comment: The pods and containers are running on Google cloud in us-central1 region @P....

Comment: Are you using a GKE cluster with a public API endpoint or are you a private endpoint and tunneling through a proxy?

You might also want to try using Cloud Shell from the GCP console and see how fast things run just to eliminate the possibility of the issue being with the control plane itself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to consistently get under 40 seconds of response time. I feel this is some what consistent and better compared to > 2 minutes, > 90 seconds response time.

I added the below to my ~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config-xxx files and then generated the kubectl config

```
[container]
cluster = dev // replace dev with your cluster name
```